# How to remove a specific HTML tag (and its content)?

Tags: regex, perl

I can't find the right keyword. I have this string :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

<table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 490px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Duis consequat varius aliquam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

<table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 490px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Duis consequat varius aliquam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
```

My attempt :

```
<table(.*)[^>]*>.*?
```

[image]

[RegExr link](http://regexr.com/51874).

This is for a script using perl that I'll make to remove table tags from a specific db table field. My attempt was targeting the table tag first and replace them with blank using perl.

Comment: I don't think Regex is the right tool for this. You should do that using some HTML parser

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, you say that you want to match the `Lorem Ipsum`, but your regex matches the HTML tags...

Anyways, here's some regex:

- To match the `<table>...</table>`:

```regex
/<(table)[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/g
```

- To match the Lorem Ipsum parts (or any line not beginning with a `<`):

```
/(?<=^|[\n\r])[^<\s].*(?=$|[\n\r])/g
```

Comment: My attempt was targeting the table tag first and replace them with blank using perl. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't spend your time too much with regexp. You can simply select the `table`s and their content and remove them from the actual string.

Use the following regex to select the tables first: `<table.*>[\w\W]*?<\/table>`. [Playground](https://regex101.com/r/dtMLq4/1).

Then use `string.replace` (or something similar) to remove the tables...

Demo:

```js
const contentWrapper = document.getElementById('demo-content');
const content = contentWrapper.innerHTML;
contentWrapper.innerHTML = ''; // no need to display the HTML content here
const html = content.replace(/<table.*>[\w\W]*?<\/table>/g, '');
console.log(html)
```

```html
<div id="demo-content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

<table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 490px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Duis consequat varius aliquam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

<table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 490px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I conveted your code into perl and it's working. Cheers.